# Fail to install mysql2 on bundle install ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

fail install mysql when run bundle install
i try to install rails project that use mysql2 as database, but i got this error when try to install mysql

```
-----
Don't know how to set rpath on your system, if MySQL libraries are not in path mysql2 may not load
-----
-----
Setting libpath to /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.0.26/lib
-----
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/ext/mysql2
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/ext/mysql2
make "DESTDIR="
compiling client.c
compiling infile.c
compiling mysql2_ext.c
compiling result.c
compiling statement.c
linking shared-object mysql2/mysql2.bundle
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/'
ld: library not found for -lssl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [mysql2.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/mysql2-0.5.3 for
inspection.
Results logged to
/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/extensions/-darwin-20/2.6.0/mysql2-0.5.3/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.5.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.3' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before
bundling.

In Gemfile:
  mysql2
```

seems like 'bundle' try to access `ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/'`

meanwhil openssl path is on : `opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/`

how to change `'-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/'` to `opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/`

someone can help ?

Answer (score 0):

Please install the following Linux packages if you're using Linux:

```sh
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git curl libssl-dev libreadline-dev zlib1g-dev autoconf bison build-essential libyaml-dev libreadline-dev libncurses5-dev libffi-dev libgdbm-dev
```

many RubyGems required native libraries from them.

and run `bundle install` again.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happens to me in Rails 6.1.4.1 (Ruby 3.0.1p64).

I have tried to executed `brew info openssl`, then follow display some guide.

`echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"' >> /Users/user/.bash_profile`

$ sw_vers

- ProductName: Mac OS X
- ProductVersion: 10.14.4